# How to know the last file I have deleted on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I was intending to delete a file using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. I did that, but I discovered that the file is still there, and I deleted another one, but I don't know which file is gone. Is there a log or something to track files operations?

Comment: Here's a great reason to actually use the Recycle Bin. Don't shift-delete unless you've got a really really good reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install (but not on the same drive as the file deleted from) a recovery utility like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to scan the volume for deleted files.

Comment: So there's no windows feature to track that ?

Comment: @Ahmed - why should there be? You told Windows to delete the file, so it did.

Comment: @Ahmed the Windows feature to track that is the Del key. You can then look into the Recycle Bin to see a "log" of what you deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not have a log of files deleted.  You'll need a recovery utility, or a recent backup to recover the deleted file (you do keep backups, right?).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows backup enabled, Windows 7 has a feature that lets you restore a directory to a previous version.  You can right click on the direct and click "Restore to previous version" and it will let you revert it.  You can copy the contents of your current folder to a temp directory to avoid losing recent progress.